# JPA Hibernate One-to-One relationship Error

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to Implement OneToOne Relationship bw 3 entities but facing this hashcode related error. I have 3 classes in 2 classes i am trying access that one entity.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with `CompanyAccessRights` but with that both:

- `Company` contains reference to `CompanyEmploymentSettings` and
- `CompanyEmploymentSettings` contains reference to `Company`

The lomboks `@EqualsAndHashCode` is calculating the hashcode by calling the `hashCode()` method on all the complex type fields, so the problem is that `CompanyEmploymentSettings.hashCode()` is calling the `Company.hashCode()` and then the `Company.hashCode()` is calling the `CompanyEmploymentSettings.hashCode()` and again, and again, until you use all the stack memory - the StackOverflowException.

To fix this, you can remove one of those fields or you can mark these fields with `@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude` to exclude this field in hashCode calculations

Answer (score 0):

Try using `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` for `@OneToOne` relationship;

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "company_access_rights")
private  CompanyAccessRights companyAccessRights;
```

Hope it can solve your problem.